# Writing WAV files, and make a copy for the wav file

Tags: python, wav

I have a question about writing WAV file.
Here are some information:

**Writes a WAV file named filename with two channels, two bytes sample width,
frame rate as given by `framerate` , with `len(sound`) samples, compression type '`NONE`' , and compression
name '`not compressed`**'

Here is my code:

```
import wave
import struct

def loadstereowav(filename):
    w = wave.open(filename, 'r')
    nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname = w.getparams()
    assert nchannels == 2 and sampwidth == 2 and comptype == 'NONE'
    frames = w.readframes(nframes * nchannels)
    sound = struct.unpack_from((str(nframes)+'h') * nchannels, frames)
    w.close()
    return framerate, sound


def savestereowav(filename, framerate, sound):
    w1 = wave.open(filename, "w")
    for i in range(0, len(sound)):
        w1.write(struct.pack('>h', framerate))
```

Here are some test case :

```
>>> rate, sound = loadstereowav('love.wav')
>>> savestereowav('love_copy.wav', rate, sound)
```

I need to write a `savestereowav(filename, framerate, sound)` function to Loading and saving a file should produce a copy.

For example, load a "**love.wav**" and make a copy with "**love_copy.wav**"

But, i have not idea about how to deal with the WAV file.

Anyone help me with this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy the file without modification (same `nchannels`, same `sampwidth`, etc), you can copy the file without having to analyse/understand its contents: `shutils.copyfile()` should do the trick

On the other hand, if you need to transform the data (ex. change sample rate, number of channels, etc), you will need two things:

1. Understand the `wav` file format.  Search for "wav file format" on the net (ex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV).  The `wave`module only provides the `readframes()` method, but you will have to manually manage the data.
2. Depending on what transformation you want, you will need some kind of signal processing method (for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28signal_processing%29).  This can be a broad question.

Since you included a `framerate` parameter in the `savestereowav` function, I assumed you want to resample.  But in your test case, you use the same `rate`.

Answer (score 0):

as I can see you already have it... it is just a minor tweak.
When you load a WAV file, first you open it and retrieve all the parameters available. You can decide whether you use them or not. In practice, you only need the first four, being the number of channels (1 for mono, 2 for stereo), sample rate, the sample width, and the number of frames. Because the track in this code must be stereo, otherwise you fall in the assert case, you have to read the frames for each channel (left and right channels for stereo).
The sound is comprised after you unpack into bytes and then you close it.
Now you have all the information you need to clone or copy your WAV file.

Then, the rest is the inverse procedure, you create a fresh WAV file, set the same parameters from the original track, and you have to write frame by frame via the pack function.

```
import wave, struct

def loadstereowav(filename):
    w = wave.open(filename, 'r')
    nchannels, sample_width, sample_rate, nframes, comptype, compname = w.getparams()
    assert nchannels == 2 and sample_width == 2 and comptype == 'NONE'
    frames = w.readframes(nframes * nchannels)
    sound = struct.unpack_from((str(nframes)+'h') * nchannels, frames)
    w.close()
    return sample_rate, nchannels, sample_width, sound

def savestereowav(filename, sample_rate, n_channels, sample_width, sound):
    # Add file parameters
    w1 = wave.open(filename, "w")
    w1.setnchannels(n_channels)
    w1.setsampwidth(sample_width)
    w1.setframerate(sample_rate)
    for i in range(0, len(sound)):
        w1.writeframesraw(struct.pack('<h', sound[i])) ## Copy each frame

srate, channels, swidth, sound = loadstereowav('Hit.wav')
savestereowav('Hit_copy.wav', srate, channels, swidth, sound)
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.